# How to effectively handle removal of objects with Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a button that creates and apply force every time the the button is touched.
How do I prevent this from leaking memory?

I am using director class to change from scene to scene.
Here is the code:

```
-- Fire the rocket from the jet position
local function fireTheRocket(event)
    if event.phase == "ended" then
      local fireBall = display.newImage( "rocket.png")
      fireBall.x = jet.x; 
      fireBall.y = jet.y; 

      GUI:insert(fireBall);

      physics.addBody(fireBall, "dynamic")
      fireBall:applyForce( 1000, 0, fireBall.x, fireBall.y )
    end
end
fireBtn:addEventListener("touch", fireTheRocket)
```

Comment: My opinion in add this images to one array.set timer to delete the child images in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like that:
(insert it after aplayng a force)

```
local function DestroyRocket()
  fireBall:removeSelf()
  fireball = nil
end
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, DestroyRocket)
```

It destroy your rocket after 1 sec. Or you can do in [onCollision](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection) if you want to destroy it when it collide with some other objects.